# ionic-plugin-keyboard not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I’m creating a new app using PhoneGap.
I need to use the keyboard events, and I can’t make them work. I'm testing only in an Android device.

I’ve read all the other questions about it and none of the suggested solutions works for me.
I've created a pretty simple project now trying to solve this specific issue.

The idea is: I have and input and a box. When device is ready, I change the color of the box (this works). When I click on the input and it shows the keyboard, I want to change the color of the box, and when I close the keyboard I want to change the color again.

My **html**

```
        <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
           <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

           <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

           <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>

                <form><input type="number" name="amount"></form>
                <div id="box"></div>


                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


                <script type="text/javascript">app.initialize();
                </script>
            </body>
```

This is my **main.js**.
*deviceready* event works on my device correctly and change the color of the box. But nothing about *hidekeyboard* and *showkeyboard*

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();}

 function onDeviceReady(){
        $('#box').css({'background-color': 'red'}); 
        document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onHide, false);
        document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onShow, false);}

 function onHide() {
        $('#box').css({'background-color': 'green'});  }

 function onShow() {
        $('#box').css({'background-color': 'black'}); }
```

I added this line in the **config.xml**:

```
<plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" source="pgb" />
```

I also tried to add code in **index.html** but I removed it because it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your keyboardhide and keyboardshow eventListeners

try

native.keyboardshow
native.keyboardhide